# Per each record, select also the data with the highest value for the record

Tags: php, mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

Good evening,

I've got the following two tables:

#### scripts

```
*----------------------------*
| user | script_id |   name  |
*----------------------------*
| 408  |    1      | script1 |
| 408  |    3      | script2 |
*----------------------------*
```

#### script_versions

```
*--------------------------------*
| id | version |      script     |
*--------------------------------*
|  1 |    1    | print "script1" |
|  1 |    2    | print "script2" |
|  3 |    0    |  print "other1" |
|  3 |    1    |  print "other2" |
*--------------------------------*
```

The table `scripts` contains some general information about a script, for example its name and the user ID of its owner. The table `script_versions` contains the code of all the different versions per each script.

Now what I want to retrieve from the database:

**I want to get the newest version (that means the highest `version` number) of all scripts for a given `user`.**

For example with the given data the query should return:

#### Wanted result

```
*-------------------------------------------------*
| id | version |      script     | user |   name  |
*-------------------------------------------------*
|  1 |    2    | print "script2" | 408  | script1 |
|  3 |    1    |  print "other2" | 408  | script2 |
*-------------------------------------------------*
```

#### What I've tried so far

This is my query right now. It does not work as it does not always select *the newest version* (in fact, it currently always selects the oldest) of all the scripts.

Code:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM scripts 
  LEFT 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT * 
         FROM script_versions 
       GROUP 
         BY id 
      ORDER 
          BY version DESC 
      ) AS versions 
          ON scripts.script_id = versions.id 
      WHERE scripts.user = ?
```

### Edit:

This question is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column), because the mentioned is not about ordering / sorting the result (by the newest version).

Comment: Why did you tag this with `php`?

Comment: @Xatenev I'm implementing the query within php, but I can remove it if you want :)

Comment: Why don't you simply reverse the ORDER BY clause if its working except for the order being wrong.

Comment: @Xatenev That doesn't change anything, I think that's because of the `GROUP BY` function

Comment: Your comments in the edit are incorrect — this question is exactly a duplicate because the versions are what you want the maximum of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
select scripts.id, v.version, v.script, scripts.user, scripts.name
from scripts s
inner join
(select id, max(version) as version from script_versions group by id) aux
on aux.id = s.script_id
inner join script_versions v on v.id = aux.id and v.version = aux.version
where user = ?
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly, apart from a little spelling mistake. Could you maybe accept my edit? :)

Comment: Ups! :) Accepted